# prisma PANIC:could not figure out an ID in create

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

Prisma client just crashed with the following error : `PANIC : could not figure out an ID in create`.
when trying to create a new user. it was an ordinary CRUD operation.

did anyone faced a similar problem and what have you done to overcome it.

env:

- Node : v21.18.3
- OS : windows
- Prisma client : 2.163.1
- db provider : mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was that i was using a dummy mysql table where ID column was not set to primary key and auto increment (somehow ???).

fixed the table structure and now everything works just fine.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Could it be because I use uuid() for the ID column?